# ASP .Net Output Caching and Ajax Control toolkit

Tags: caching, asp.net-ajax, outputcache

I'd like to know if there's a special way of implementing output caching and using a control from the ajax control toolkit. I keep getting a javascript error on a page with output caching and a tab control that says: ajaxtoolkit (my assembly prefix) is undefined.

This is the directive I added:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="3600" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

Comment: Are you placing this on a user control or a page that inherits from a master page?

Comment: I'm placing it on a user control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the output caching cannot be combined with the generated scripts by the AJAX framework yet (hopefully in a future version some similar behavior will be available *crossing fingers*), other type of optimization approach has to be made like replacing the ScriptManager for the ToolScriptManager.

http://blog.creonfx.com/performance/howto-optimize-rendering-speed-of-aspnet-ajax-websites

Answer (score 0):

> Microsoft does not support output
>   caching in combination with
>   ScriptControls, Extenders, or
>   ScriptManagerProxies that need
>   ScriptReferences. A workaround to the
>   issue is to include the script
>   references these resources require on
>   the main script manager, outside the
>   output cached control.

More info [here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=389102)