# Output Caching - why doesn't it seem to do the job?

Tags: asp.net, outputcache

I have quite a big user control which creates an ASP.NET tab menu and within each tab a lengthy set of icons/menus.  The menu is dynamically created from the database.  I thought I could wrap the user control with an output cache directive to speed things up.  I set OutputCache varybyparam="none" and duration to 120 seconds.

When I navigate to my page, the usercontrol containing the tab menus and icons etc just vanishes? I thought ASP.NET was supposed to deliver some HTML that would previously have been cached.

So why isn't this working? It doesn't seem to do what the label says on the tin?!? ;)

Comment: Could you post the full OutputCache directive?

Comment: <%@ OutputCache Duration="120" VaryByParam="None" %>
One the first page load I get all the menus (this is using a custom SiteMapProvider), but when I hit refresh the whole control is missing?
Actually, is there a problem with using AJAX with this because I can see an error on this line in firebug:

Sys.Application.add_init(function() {
1239 $create(AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel, {"headerTab":$get("__tab_ctl00_cphMainMaster_ucModuleTabList_tcModules_ctl00")}, null, {"owner":"ctl00_cphMainMaster_ucModuleTabList_tcModules"}, $get("ctl00_cphMainMaster_ucModuleTabList_tcModules_ctl00"));
1240});

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by mixing AJAX and the outputcache. Both don't play well together. This is covered by the following post:
[See Post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664107/asp-net-output-caching-and-ajax-control-toolkit)